# Open Source login systems, what is good?

Tags: open-source, authentication

I am starting a a new web development project and I am tired of coding login systems. This is the kind of thing that must have been done dozens of times before. I really want to use someone else's code, because it is easier than rolling my own, and it will likely be better. I prefer open source for all the usual reasons, but mostly I want the ability to change it if I don't like something and bugfixes are easier than designing a whole thing.

I just need a login system, something that manages the username/password stuff and user registration. I don't need a whole CMS.

I am already looking at openid.net, but What open source login systems have you worked with? What other login systems have you heard of?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OpenID is definitely the best solution and there are plennty of open source libraries for all kinds of languages out there. Hava look at [openidenabled.com](http://openidenabled.com/).

Answer (score 11):

OpenID works really well.  Given the recent wave of adoptions, I think OpenID is the best bet.  It is cross-platform and has libraries for all the major development platforms (php, python, perl, ruby, .net, java, c++).  I have implemented it for DotNetNuke and found it was relatively painless.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know what technologies (language & platforms) you prefer or have as requirements, but we have implemented [CAS](http://www.jasig.org/cas) at my workplace and it has worked pretty well.

CAS itself is implemented in Java, but as the frontpage says, it has client libraries and integrations to numerous other technologies and pltaforms.

Answer (score 1):

I wound up going with mod_auth_openid. It is super simple and prevents unneeded complication at other levels. but the code is not perfect, and I may have to adjust it later.